# How can I fix the redirect chain after implementing ssl on wordpress?

Tags: htaccess, html, ssl

After implementing ssl on wordpress, I wanted to force a redirection to a site with the following characteristics:

**non www, ssl, with trailing slash**

Unfortunately it only works in some cases.

For instance, instead of redirecting from a site with these characteristics (http, non www, without trailing slash to https, non www with trailing slash), it redirects like this:

- `http://example.com/foo` over `https://example.com/foo` to `https://example.com/foo/`.

I also have an issue with redirecting a www, http site without trailing slash to an https, non www, with trailing slash site.

Currently, it redirects from `http://www.example.com/foo` via `http://example.com/foo` to `https://example.com/foo` and `https://example.com/foo/`.

Therefore my question is: How can I fix this? Is this done somehow by the Wordpress system?

Enclosed you'll find my `.htaccess` file. I hope you can help me.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-content\/cache\/(all|wpfc-mobile-cache)
```

Could this be somehow caused by WordPress? I've mentioned this before, but there is also a rewrite code from WordPress.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The `.htaccess` file you've posted (in two parts) is not complete and the order of directives is important. This order is not clear from what you've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing this in `.htaccess` then I wouldn't try to do this in a single redirect. The longest "chain" should be two redirects (1, 2 or even 3 redirects makes no difference for SEO):

1. Canonicalise the HTTP to HTTPS and www to non-www in the first redirect
2. Append the trailing slash in the second redirect.

(If, however, you are implementing [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) then you would need to implement the HTTP to HTTPS redirect (on the same hostname) first. Then canonicalise the subdomain. This potentially makes a maximum of 3 redirects.)

This appears to be what you are seeing in your first example.

It's possible to append the trailing slash in `.htaccess`, however, you've not shown this code so I'm assuming WordPress is configured to do this?

> Currently, it redirects from `http://www.example.com/foo` via `http://example.com/foo` to `https://example.com/foo` and `https://example.com/foo/`.

However, this doesn't correlate with the directives you posted, assuming these are at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
> ```

These directives only redirect to `https://`, so it's not clear where your second stage redirect to `http://example.com/foo` is coming from? Unless maybe you are seeing a cached response?

Presumably, you are already linking to URLs with a trailing slash throughout your application, and you previously implemented a canonical www to non-www redirect, so any requests for `http://www.example.com/foo` should be a relatively rare occurrence. (?)